# Modifying axes and labels of overlaid matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

I'm having trouble formatting the seaborn graph, where I overlaid two graphs (line & bar).  Say I have the following code so far:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
df1["a"].plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax1)
df2["b"].plot(kind='line', marker='d', ax=ax2)
ax.set_xticklabels(('2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'))
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax1.set_ylabel('Label A')
ax2.yaxis.tick_left()
ax2.set_ylabel('Label B')
ax1.set_xticklabels(('2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'))
plt.show()
```

Which produce something like this:

[image: imageOfGraph]

I would really appreciate if I can get advice on how to:

- avoid the overlap of labels and ticks
- make the label B axis into a percentage from 0 ~ 100 (and yes, most of my data hover around 30%, but I want to indicate how low that is.) Basically, I wanted to try axes.ylim(("0","100")) but it didn't work for me.
- showing the entire width of each bar (the very first and last bars got cut by axes but I'm really not sure how to avoid it)

Terribly sorry if I'm making basic mistakes here, but it would be very helpful as no one seem to be active in queries in my online course.

*edit:
Please note that my screenshot has VERY large numbers on one of the y-axis as I just took picture of my actual working notebook.  However, please feel free to use the following sample dataset for the demonstration:

```
df1 =  [39, 30, 40, 36, 28, 42]
df2 = [5, 8, 7, 3, 2, 6]
```

Comment: I'm also concerned about the 1e11 in the upper left, which implies that the "8" on the y-axis is not `8`, but `800,000,000,000`. Is that what you want? It would be best if you could provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that's *minimal* but shows these same problems and which we could run (just make some fake data for it, like `data1 =  [4, 3, 7, 7, 2, 6]` or whatever).

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out.  The actual code I was working on (where I screenshot the graph) has a large quantity of aggregate budget.  (I might as well as clean them into xx millions/thousands form later on...) but yes, I might put a random sample data frame just in case!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try address your problems with the code:

```
from matplotlib import ticker

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# don't try to force tick left/right. Swap the axes
df1["a"].plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax2)
df2["b"].plot(kind='line', marker='d', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xticklabels(('2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'))

# disable these
# ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
# ax2.yaxis.tick_left()

# format to percentage
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x}%"))

ax1.set_ylabel('Label B')
ax2.set_ylabel('Label A')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And you get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out here.  I was able to align the labels of axes and x-axis ticks as I would have liked!  If possible, I would also love to know how I can have the y-axis (of percentage) zoomed out too (ie. 0% ~ 100%).  I tried setting y-lim("0", "100") but ax does not seem to have that attribute. :(